# Factory for ERC1400, deployed contract not working

Tags: solidity

Hey I have written a factory for the ERC1400 Token by https://github.com/ConsenSys/ERC1400. When I run the test for issueByPartition I get a revert Error. Other tests like isIssuable works.
If I deploy the contract without the factory the customized issueByPartition  test passed.
Why is my factory deployed contract not working?

### ERC1400Factory.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

import "../../ERC1400.sol";
 
contract ERC1400Factory {

    ERC1400[] public deployedERC1400;
    bytes32[] public tokenDefaultPartitions;
    
    address public certificateSigner;
 
    constructor(address certificat, bytes32[] memory tokenDefaul) public {
  
    certificateSigner = certificat;
    tokenDefaultPartitions = tokenDefaul;
    }
   
    function createERC1400(string memory name, string memory symbol, uint256 granularity, address[] memory controllers) public  {
         
        ERC1400 newERC1400 = new ERC1400(name, symbol, granularity, controllers, certificateSigner, tokenDefaultPartitions);
   
        deployedERC1400.push(newERC1400);
    }

    function getDeployedERC1400() public view returns (ERC1400[] memory ) {
        return deployedERC1400;
    }
}
```

### ERC1400Factory.test.js

```
const ERC1400Factory = artifacts.require('ERC1400Factory');
const ERC1400 = artifacts.require('ERC1400');

const CERTIFICATE_SIGNER = '0xe31C41f0f70C5ff39f73B4B94bcCD767b3071630';
const VALID_CERTIFICATE = '0x1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000';
const issuanceAmount = 1000;

const partition1 = '0x5265736572766564000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'; // Reserved in hex
const partition2 = '0x4973737565640000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'; // Issued in hex
const partition3 = '0x4c6f636b65640000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'; // Locked in hex
const partitions = [partition1, partition2, partition3];

contract('ERC1400Factory', function ([controller, tokenHolder, owner]) {
  beforeEach(async function () {
    this.erc1400factory = await ERC1400Factory.new(CERTIFICATE_SIGNER, partitions);
    await this.erc1400factory.createERC1400('test', 'tet', 1, [controller], { from: controller });
  });

  describe('ERC1400', function () {
    it('issueERC1400', async function () {
      let address = await this.erc1400factory.getDeployedERC1400();
      
      let erc1400 = await ERC1400.at(address[0]);
      
      await erc1400.issueByPartition(partition1, tokenHolder, issuanceAmount, VALID_CERTIFICATE, { from: owner });
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```js
let address = await this.erc1400factory.createERC1400('test', 'tet', 1, [controller], { from: controller });
```

Transactions don't have return values. What you're getting back in `address` is probably something like the transaction hash.

You'll need to access `deployedERC1400` to find out the address of the newly-created contract, something like this (completely untested):

```js
await this.erc1400factory.createERC1400('test', 'tet', 1, [controller], { from: controller });
let address = this.erc1400factory.getDeployedERC1400().pop();
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I have adapted the code. But it does not work yet.

Comment: Your code seems to try to assign the whole `deployedERC1400` array to `address` instead of just the last element. I assume you tried my code first and found that it didn't work? Try printing out the value of `address` to debug further.

Comment: Yes I tried your code but it does not work. I changed my code again but I still get the same error: Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert. Maybe the error is caused by the inheritance at the erc 1400

Comment: Did you try printing out the value of `address`? What was it?

Comment: I print out the address and get 0x282C6018b44F0752597Aa60cdE4C0C66Af159C1C, some function of the contract works but the issueByPartition not.